# Capturing window's screenshot excluding certain HWND's styles (WS_SYSMENU)

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I'm trying to periodically compare snapshots of the same window every few of seconds. Even though that technically the window doesn't change, pictures remains the same, i still get notified that something has changed with in the picture, I'm using good old `BitBlt` function to capture a specific window. and `Zlib's CRC32` to compare results.

Here's an example of 2 identical pictures, the sole difference is the windows' caption(`untitled paint`) color. Whenever the window has the focus it's black, and gray otherwise. Since I'm not the owner of the HWND, Is there a better way of taking a picture without calculating the actual size of the window minus GetSystemMetrices(SM_CYSIZEFRAME / SM_CXSIZE) than changing the style.

My code:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT rect;
    ::GetWindowPlacement(windowDesc.hWnd, &rect);
    if (SW_SHOWMINIMIZED == rect.showCmd)
    {
        return;
    }

    CImage img;
    img.Create(
        rect.rcNormalPosition.right - rect.rcNormalPosition.left,
        rect.rcNormalPosition.bottom - rect.rcNormalPosition.top, 
        32);

    HWND hWnd = windowDesc.hWnd;
    std::shared_ptr<HDC__> spSrcHdc(::GetDC(hWnd), [hWnd](HDC hdc) {::ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc); });
    //::BitBlt(img.GetDC(), 0, 0, img.GetWidth(), img.GetHeight(), spSrcHdc.get(), 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ::PrintWindow(hWnd, img.GetDC(), 0x2);
    BITMAP bmp = { 0 };
    if (!::GetObject((HBITMAP)img, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp))
    {
        throw std::exception("Failed to retrieve raw bmp buffer");
    }

    unsigned long ulbmpCRC = crc32(0, 
        (BYTE*)bmp.bmBits, bmp.bmWidthBytes * bmp.bmHeight);

    if (0 != ulbmpCRC && ulbmpCRC == windowDesc.crc)
    {
    }
```

[image]
[image]

And another issue i failed to solve is when textboxes are present. The very fact that i have the cursor flickering, it generates different CRC32 values. yet again, can i use BitBlt with the ability to ignore the phenomenon?

Comment: There is no generic way to do what you want. The system metric values are wrong for themed UIs, and you cannot simply ask for the client rectangle either, since some applications (like Visual Studio) do not use a standard non-client area. And while this is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd like to save screenshots whenever a picture changes. though what earlierly mention in fact is change. I'd like to take a screenshot(save the picture) whenever the drawing itself changes

Comment: Are you asking about MS Paint in particular? Either way, though, your approach is brittle. Even if you identify the drawing area and compare screenshots, you'll get false positives whenever the user uses the scrollbar to move the drawing around. Or simply changes the zoom level. Or enables/disables pixel grids.

Comment: Not mspaint, a general solution. I’d to exclude only sysmenu changes and general cursor flickering inside textbox controls

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally flawed. It isn't going to work. Ever. Using your proposed algorithm, you'll get change notifications, whenever part of the 'interesting area' is obscured by another window, or when the user decides to resize the viewport. It will fail for windows that have requested their display affinity as `WDA_MONITOR`, or those windows that use a DirectX rendering surface. You might as well spend your time solving a problem for which there is a solution. This one isn't one of those.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the client area of the target window, you can send it a [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634(v=vs.85).aspx) message.  This should enable you to determine the size of the caption bar reliably for most applications, something like:

```
RECT r;
GetWindowRect (hTargetWnd, &r);
SendMessage (hTargetWnd, WM_NCCALCSIZE, FALSE, (LPARAM) &r);
```

As for the flashing caret problem, you could try remembering the checksums for the last *two* different screens you have seen.  Then you have a chance of working out when the window is, in effect, switching back and forth between two states.

That, and more sophisticated comparison logic (such as walking the list of child windows to look for edit controls to see if any changes are confined to the contents of such controls), should make it possible to achieve most of what you want.

Comment: This assumes, that windows will actually use the system services for non-client area management. Visual Studio doesn't, as far as I know. UWP applications certainly don't, as they aren't even using `HWND`s for their presentation. This answer hardly even addresses the issue the OP has identified. I posted comments about issues that the OP hasn't even considered.

Comment: Yes, I know that many apps play games when painting the non-client area, and you raise a good point about UWP apps, I don't know much about those. You might be able to bitblt out of a partially covered window successfully with DWM composition enabled though, I haven't tested that recently.  In the end, I guess a lot depends on whether the OP is willing to accept some limitations in whatever solution he ends up with.  He will have to experiment and put some work in.  And there is also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx) to consider.